# Who sees a private list

Tags: list, security

1. If I set the option of "Read items that were created by the user", who other than the user can still view it?
2. Where can I restrict the list of people who can still view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @kolten said users with "Full control", or control permission (Owners) can also view the items. They can change the list settings anyway, so hiding such items from them would not make sense.
This also means anyone with the access level "Administer lists".
I did a test, and it seems users with the access level to override/break checkout also can view items.

I don't know any way to check item permission on one single item OOTB, but it is possible to loop all users and check them one and one against the item with the [SPListItem.DoesUserHavePermissions method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472022.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

These items can only be viewed by the Site Collection Administrators, Farm Administrators, anyone with audit level access defined in Central Admin, and the user that created the item.

You can edit Site Collection Admins from the option in the Site Collection Site Settings.

You can edit the Farm Administrators in Central Admin.

You can edit audit level permissions in Central Admin.